# Spring Boot Validation information not displayed in Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

My classes are written in **Spring Boot Java** and I use **Swagger 2** to generate their documentation.
I am using *spring-fox version 2.9.0*.

To show the validation constraints (@min, @max, @pattern, etc) in Swagger UI, I added the following lines to my *application.java*, where *showExtensions(true)*, but that didn't work.
Desired result in Swagger UI

[image]

What should I change to get the wanted result?

```
@Bean
UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
  return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder() 
      .deepLinking(true)
      .displayOperationId(false)
      .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1)
      .defaultModelExpandDepth(1)
      .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.EXAMPLE)
      .displayRequestDuration(false)
      .docExpansion(DocExpansion.NONE)
      .filter(false)
      .maxDisplayedTags(null)
      .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA)
      .showExtensions(true)
      .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA)
      .supportedSubmitMethods(UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS)
      .validatorUrl(null)
      .build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UiConfiguration` is fine. What you need to do is (to activate the **Springfox Support for JSR-303** cf. [Springfox Reference Documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)):

- add the `springfox-bean-validators` dependency to your `pom.xml`:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version> <!-- or any version you like -->
  </dependency>
  ```
- Import the configuration from the `springfox-bean-validators` module:

  ```
  ...
  @Import({springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class})
  public class SwaggerDocumentationConfig { ... }
  ```

Now you should be able to see the desired information at the top of annotated attributes in Swagger UI.